# Ошибка при компиляции: доступ к файлу LoadLibraryExW отсутствует

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, pyinstaller

Установил pyinstaller. Прописываю в терминале pyinstaller main.py и начинается процесс компиляции, но под конец выводится ошибка:

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
        raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
    win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'Доступ к этому файлу из системы отсутствует.')
```

Код программы:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QRadialGradient, QPainter, QPainterPath, QPen, QBrush, QGradient, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPointF, Qt, QRect

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
 d = 0
 def __init__(self):
     super().__init__()

     self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
     self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

     self.resize(600, 400)


 def paintEvent(self, event):
     painter = QPainter(self)

     radialGrad = QRadialGradient(0.3, 0.7, 0.05)
     radialGrad.setCoordinateMode(QGradient.ObjectBoundingMode)
     radialGrad.setSpread(QGradient.ReflectSpread)
     radialGrad.setColorAt(0, QColor('#0250c5'))
     radialGrad.setColorAt(1, QColor('#2575fc'))
     painter.setBrush(radialGrad)
    
     painter.drawRect(self.rect())                                    # +++ rect

     painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.white))  # white red
     painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, -1))                    # +++
     painter.drawRect(100,  self.height()-12, 1, 1)                 # +++ height
     painter.drawRect(200, self.height()-12+self.d, 2, 2)                    # +++ height
     painter.drawRect(300, self.height()-12, 3, 3)                    # +++ height
     self.d -= 1
     if self.d < -400:
         self.d = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Как скомпилировать программу в .exe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57180580/pyinstaller-win32ctypes-pywin32-pywintypes-error-1920-loadlibraryexw-syst

Comment: Ответы от туда мне не помогли